Min-max optimization and prediction of a parameter in a mathematical model
Context
Hello, everyone; let me preface this by saying that my background is in CS and not mathematics, but I do have a background in calculus, statistics, and discrete mathematics.
The issue at hand is that I have some observations (data) that are a result of very time-consuming simulations, and the values are based on physical phenomena whose underlying math has not yet been fully understood.
Problem Definition
The simulation consists of 10 parameters that define the system design, almost like a configuration of the system. Then there is a setting in the simulation for the "render quality", called the R factor (constrained to values of 1 to 8). A higher R takes more time to finish the simulation but may not always lead to a better result.
The metric I'm trying to optimize is a factor called Q, such that I get the highest possible Q for the lowest R setting. There exist some situations in which increasing the R by 1 increases Q by orders of magnitude, while other times, it does not improve Q by much.
Objective
I would like to capture the potential improvements in Q based on the R setting with a probabilistic model (something that would give me a probability distribution of confidence). The issue lies in that I'm trying to figure out a way to learn from the observations of a model, and then when I get new data, the model would tell me which R setting is the optimal one to maximize Q while minimizing R.
I'm not expecting any full-on models, but any pointers that would point me in the correct direction would be very much appreciated, I was thinking of using MLEs to estimate Q-score, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with that and how to get certainty distributions, and whether it is even suitable for my use case
Note:
I apologize if this is slightly irrelevant to this stack exchange, but because this is at the intersection of mathematics and software, I'm unsure whether this will be relevant here or on stack overflow. So I'm trying my luck here first. I'm also planning on writing the code for the potential solution, but I'll be fine on that front

Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{11}$ denoting the 11 parameters, i.e., the 10 parameters plus $R$.  Let $f$ be some function (which you are trying to find) so that $f(x)$ is a reasonable estimate to the $Q$ value associated with configuration $x$.  Then one plausible approach is to try to learn a model $f$ that does a good job at estimating $Q$.  Once you have such a model, given any choice of 10 parameters, you can evaluate it at all 8 values of $R$ and choose a value of $R$ based on the predicted $Q$ values.
How to learn $R$?  Presumably, each time you run a simulation, you can keep track of the parameters $x$ and the observed $Q$ value.  Collect all of these pairs $(x,Q)$ into a training set $T$.  Then, train some kind of predictor (maybe a neural network) to minimize a loss function, say
$$l(x,Q) = (f(x)-Q)^2, \qquad L = \sum_{(x,Q) \in T} l(x,Q).$$
So now the goal is to find $f$ that minimizes $L$.  This can be done, for instance, by supervised training of a neural network, with MSE loss (or some other regression loss).
It might be possible to do better, given more knowledge about your particular domain, but with the information provided in the question, it's hard to say what will well or what won't.  Typically, in machine learning, you have to try a bunch of approaches and see how well each works.

From what I can see, this predicts a single value without presenting a confidence interval or a certainty distribution. How can I incorporate that into this model?

@A.Sal, possibilities might include using an ensemble of models or a Gaussian process.
